# Division in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, division, signed

I am trying to divide two 32 bit std_logic_vector signals (see code below). both inputs are variable.
when I write a separate module and test it, it's OK but when I use it as a part of the other module it can not be simulated. Simulation has no error but it's stopped and links me to this module.
by the way I'm working with Xilinx

```
library IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
entity DivEx is
port(
    X   : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
    Y   : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
    R   : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0)
);
end DivEx;

architecture Behavioral of DivEx is
begin
R <= std_logic_vector(to_signed(to_integer(signed(X) / signed(Y)),32));
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: actual error reports or messages?

Comment: nothing it stops simulation I thinks it's related to number of bits.

Comment: It might not have stopped ... give it a few more hours! Or more logically, convert both X and Y to integer, for faster simulation.

Comment: In package numeric_std function to_integer there's an assertion for detecting metavalues  - assert NO_WARNING report "NUMERIC_STD.TO_INTEGER: metavalue detected, returning 0" severity WARNING.  Your code appears likely to encounter this at least once. It's not unheard of for a simulator to allow you to specify the severity level which will stop simulation.  I'd check whether or not my simulation would stop on WARNING. Note @Brian asked for actual error reports/messages. With a test bench DivEx divides under ghdl unless --assert-level=warning is specified. BreakOnAssertion in modelsim.ini.

Comment: To avoid assert due to unknown bits for `to_integer`, you can skip the (seemingly unnecessary) integer convert if you write `R <= std_logic_vector(signed(X) / signed(Y));`.  Unknown argument bits are propagated through the signed division, and thereby not suppressed in simulation as when using `to_integer`, but division 0 does still results in assert error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VHDL doesn't have modules.  They're called component instantiations of either declared components or directly instantiated entities or configurations.

With this test bench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity tb_divex is
end entity;

architecture foo of tb_divex is
    signal x:       std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) :=x"000000FF";
    signal y:       std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) :=x"00000005";
    signal r:       std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
begin

DUT:
    entity work.divex
        port map (
            x => x,
            y => y,
            r => r
        );

STIMULUS:
    process 
    begin
        wait for 10 ns; -- so we can see these on a waveform display
        y <= x"00000023";
        wait for 10 ns;
        x <= x"00000123";
        y <= x"00000003";
        wait for 10 ns;
        wait;      
    end process;

end architecture;
```

Which uses a directly instantiated entity we get:

[image: tb_divex_ghdl.png]

Which shows that directly instantiating your `divex` results in something that works.

You never responded to Brian Drummond's request for actual warnings/error messages which also precludes someone from determining which vendor's tools you were using.

Without seeing those and your test bench or stimulus application methodology anyone answering is handicapped.

It is possible that you were using instantiation of a component via a component declaration, in which case you may not have had the component bound.  You can analyze a VHDL design specification using a component declaration, but unless the entity has been previously analyzed into a design library whose contents are made visible by a context clause elaboration may not not bind the component to library design unit.

See IEEE Std 1076-1993/-2008 12.4.3/14.5.4 Component instantiation statements:

> Elaboration of a component instantiation statement that instantiates a
>   component declaration has no effect unless the component instance is
>   either fully bound to a design entity defined by an entity declaration
>   and architecture body or bound to a configuration of such a design
>   entity. If a component instance is so bound, then elaboration of the
>   corresponding component instantiation statement consists of the
>   elaboration of the implied block statement representing the component
>   instance and (within that block) the implied block statement
>   representing the design entity to which the component instance is
>   bound.

A component instantiation uses default binding based on it's name:

5.2.2/7.3.3 Default binding indication

> In certain circumstances, a default binding indication will apply in
>   the absence of an explicit binding indication. The default binding
>   indication consists of a default entity aspect, together with a
>   default generic map aspect and a default port map aspect, as
>   appropriate.
>
> If no visible entity declaration has the same simple name as that of
>   the instantiated component, then the default entity aspect is open....

So your `divex` component can be **open**.

In some tools managing 'projects' this can occur because the design file for divex hasn't been included in the 'project'.  Effectively it isn't analyzed into the current working library and when a library it has been analyzed into (a different project's working library) isn't made visible by context statement it simply isn't there.